# iTEXT DITO number of template in .DITO file

Tags: pdf, itext

Is there any quick way to find out how many templates (count) are created under one .DITO file ? Basically we have lot of templates created and in order to compare differences of templates between environments, wanted to know how many templates exists in one .DITO file.
Thanks for the help

Expecting a quicker way to get the count as we cannot copy paste the templates to an excel

Comment: the .DITO files are actually zip files, you can see yourself. Each .DITO file should be one template.